# SVM training set format - how to convert 3D scanned objects (of protein scanning microscope) as proper SVM input

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, training-data

I use SkiKit-learn package to implement SVM and need to implement in Python following task.
System input: 3 dimensional scanning of protein (density in each of coordinates of 256x256x256 pixels scanned sample).
Desired output: 3D coordinates location of Amino Acids (which given protein comprised of, as its concatenated building blocks), and identifying Amino Acids type (from possible 22 types).
Suggestion to use as training set: isolated scanning of known single Amino Acid from different angles, zooming, and resolutions - to get ("learn" by SVM) its general geometric shape. And to so so with all 22 Amino Acids.
And then, really analyzing of unknown protein with provided chain of its Amino Acids sequence (as text), while demanding output as described above (AAs coordinates localization, and AAs type).

Please advise: 
1. How to convert scanning samples of separated Amino Acids as input into training set?
2. How to classify output format (trivial is to numerate from 1 to 22 all groups and that's all?
3. Is SkiKit-learn package is proper environment to implement such a project?

Comment: Yes, **scikit**-learn is a good library for SVM classification in python. Do you have specific programming problems? Your questions are very general.

Comment: @UlliSchmid: Is "raw" format as is, of scanned densities is proper input as training set? I am new with both SkiKit-learn and with SVM, so I still don't get how exactly goes command which causes SVM to learn of 3D shape. Aka, is it OK to provide as input the whole scanning "cube", without certain preprocessing (like parsing of internal objects). If it's OK, please provide specific such a command, or refer to good example which has similar implementation.

Comment: SVM can handle surprisingly high dimensional data without overfitting - 256x256x256 is very very high though. To combat this you may downscale or apply some form of dimensionality reduction. This is not the place for your kind of question, though - you may want to look into http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://datascience.stackexchange.com/